# Finding total of matrix, fraction with two variables

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, summation, summation-method

I'm trying to solve summation over a matrix that has been populated with an equation using two variables.

Trying to derive the a matrix populated with the equation:

$$f(x,y)  = \frac{a}{x^2 + y - b}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

now given $\max(x) = X$ and $\max(y)=Y$, what is the sum of all the items in the matrix? ie

$$\operatorname{total}(X,Y) = \sum_{x=1}^{X} \sum_{y=1}^{Y}f(x,y)$$

thus, I am trying to derive the $$ \operatorname{total(X,Y)} $$ function, which will give a total of a matrix with entries populated using the above equation.

I **think** I need split up:
$$\operatorname{total}(X,Y) = \sum_{x=1}^{X} \sum_{y=1}^{Y} f(x,y)$$

i.e. solve for inner sigma, finding:

$$g(x; Y)=\sum_{y=1}^{Y} \frac{a}{x^2 + y - b}$$

giving equation $g(x; Y)$, then

$$\operatorname{total}(X,Y) = \sum_{x=1}^{X} g(x; Y)$$

However, I don't know if I'm right on those steps, and I'm not sure how to find the partial sum equation for both steps.

Any math wizz's able to give some suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did quite a major edit to clean up your equations. Please check if everything is still as you intended. Note that if you have a function $k(x)$, it is implied that the value of $k(x)$ depends on $x$. If you want to denote that your function is about cleaning things related to $y$ you could define the function as $f^{(y)}$ or something along those lines, but do not use $f\sigma(y)$ when $f$ is already defined, and $f\sigma(\cdot)$ actually depends on $x$ not $y$.

Comment: Also, $\operatorname{total}(x,y)$ doesn't quite make sense since its output does not depend on $x$ or $y$. Perhaps, it might make more sense if you write $\operatorname{total}(X,Y)$ where $X=\max(x)$ and $Y=\max(y)$, which are something the output actually depends on.

Comment: For this type of question, we usually approach by trying to split
$$\sum_x \sum_y f(x,y)$$
into 
$$\sum_x\sum_y (h(x)+k(y))=\sum_xh(x)+\sum_yk(y)$$

Not sure if it is possible on your function but certainly a potential approach

Comment: Thank you!  
When calling total it would be in the context of total(max_x, max_y).  ie finding the total of all entries in the matrix.
The thing that throws me is the x and y are dividing "a" (a constant).  
Thus I'm not sure if this can be split out in a... simple way. (?)